# Gnuplot: Alternatives for pm3d

Tags: gnuplot, wolfram-mathematica

I am exporting the 3D plot data from Mathematica and trying to plot it in gnuplot. I would like to put color gradient like we do in pm3d. But the constraint of pm3d is that we need a space each time when there is a sign change. Since I have a large collection of points and the format of the Mathematica output is different, is there any alternatives to pm3d?

Comment: what do you mean with "sign change"? What is the format of your current data, can you shown an example?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I think he means you need an empty line between linescans

Comment: You can convert your data to gridded data with `set dgrid3d`, although this can become expensive if you have a lot of data. `dgrid3d` offers different interpolation methods, I usually use something like `set dgrid3d 32,32 splines` (which is very slow if you have a lot of data). Use `help set dgrid3d` to check all the possibilities.

Comment: show an example of the desired output, mathematica can be made to output however you like

Comment: pm3d is a bit quirky in the way it needs the data. You could a) tell Mathematica how to store the data, b) use the `matrix` command to plot an array of numbers presented as a bidimensional table of numbers.